# Oracle SQL to_date & to_timestamp ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected & ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, to-date, to-timestamp

I have a small bit of code:

**Code**

```
SELECT to_date(it.DSTAMP, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "Date", to_timestamp(it.DSTAMP, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS Time
FROM itable it
```

**Errors**

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
>   01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
>   *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
>              incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
>              required by the format model.
>   *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
>              elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

*Error if I remove `to_date`*

> ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23
>   01850. 00000 -  "hour must be between 0 and 23"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

The `DSTAMP` field returns `24-SEP-14 08.55.33.997545000` without any formatting.

Obviously expected output is

24/09/2014 & 08:55:34

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that it.DSTAMP is a TIMESTAMP

Replace `to_date` and `to_timestamp` with `to_char`

```
SELECT to_char(it.DSTAMP, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "Date", to_char(it.DSTAMP, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS Time
FROM itable it
```