# Spring Batch: SQL error ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: oracle, jdbc, spring-batch

I'm trying to use this SQL in my spring batch reader. The SQL seems to have a problem:

```
select DISTINCT ces.COR_ENBL_STG_ID 
from HBX_BATCH_COR_ENBL_STG ces 
Inner JOIN HBX_INDV_NEG_ACTION ina ON ces.INDV_ID=ina.INDV_ID 
where ces.DISP_PROCESSED_FLAG='Y'  
AND ina.NEG_ACTION_RUN_RSN_CD in('11054','11055','11065') 
AND ces.PGM_BGN_DT+90<'#{jobExecutionContext['latest.completed.startTime']}'
```

The value of **latest.completed.start.time** is coming as '07-Oct-16 12:38:58.000000109 PM' from a tasklet using jdbctemplate and hence the SQL is throwing the following error : ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.

Just FYI the column **ces.PGM_BGN_DT** is a Date Type. I tried TO_DATE function but it didn't help. Any suggestions please?

Comment: What is data time of latest.completed.startTime? And what did you try with TO_DATE(), please show us.

Comment: This error is coming from jdbc driver and not from spring batch reader so not a spring batch reader issue. You need to fix query and data. See if these two help, [SO_Q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425515/oracle-sql-to-date-to-timestamp-ora-01858-a-non-numeric-character-was-found-w) , [SO_Q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852389/getting-error-ora-01858-a-non-numeric-character-was-found-where-a-numeric-was)

Comment: @NghiaDo latest.completed.startTime is a timestamp value. I needed it to be compared with pgm_bgn_dt which was a date. The problem was because batch was taking it as string after replacing the value and persisting it inside the single quotes. I used to_timestamp and now its comparing.

Comment: @SabirKhan Thanks for the links. They were quite useful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand latest.completed.startTime - is a string of characters.
And its look like as oracle timestamp datatype. 
If my suggestion are true, You should use format to convert string to timestamp

```
to_timestamp(latest.completed.startTime, 'dd-mon-yy HH12:MI:SS.FF AM');
```

Comment: hey @michael Piankov thanks for the help. The batch parameter latest.completed.startTime was coming as string after getting replaced with the value due to the single quotes. I used to_timestamp and now its comparing well. Thanks much :)